# Change the background color of a DIV using react antd package

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using react antd package for styling the app. How do I style the div with the default background color in antd? Below is the bootstrap way of doing it.

```
<div className="bg-default">
```

Comment: I don't think antd has color styling class like bootstrap for arbitrary divs , they wrap everything in components, maybe you want to specify which component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import LESS variables from `antd/lib/style/themes/default`

Comment: can you elaborate more? Does it mean you'd have to introduce a new `less` variable ex. `@bg-default: #bbb` or it's the default variables that need to be overridden?

Comment: Just use variables from antd default theme, please study LESS' documentation.